# Rendering contextmenu for each row of a table

Tags: c#, mouseevent, blazor

I want to attach an event handler for each row of a table.
When the user right-clicks on a `row` , i want to open a small modal next to that row.
Now in order to do this i do not know how to get the selected row.The documentation shows `UIMouseEventArgs` to be used.I see it has only one paramter `Type` which i assume is either `mousedown` or `mouseover`...etc (the type of the mouse event).

How do i get the row on which the user right-clicked?

**Table**

```
    @inherits DashboardBase
    @foreach (var ca in this.campaigns) {
                    <tr id="@ca.Id" onmousedown="@(async(ev)=>await OnClick(ev,ca))">
                        <td >@ca.Id</td>
                        <td>@ca.Name</td>
                        <td>@ca.State.Tag</td>
                        <td>@ca.CreatedAtUtc</td>
                        <td>@ca.IsPaused</td>
                        @if (this.SelectedId == ca.Id) {
                            <td><ModalHelper info="@ca"></ModalHelper></td>
                            @"test string"
                        }

                    </tr>
                }

 public class DashboardBase : BlazorComponent {

        protected long SelectedId = -1;
        [Parameter]
        protected Campaign.Dto.CampaignInfo[] campaigns { get; set; }
        protected  void OnClick(UIMouseEventArgs args,CampaignInfo campaign) {
            if (args.Button != 2) {

                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed right on campaignID:" + campaign.Id);
            this.SelectedId = campaign.Id;
            this.StateHasChanged();


        }


    }
```

**Modal**

```
@inherits ModalHelperBase
<div>
    <button onclick="@(async()=>await OnDeletePressedAsync())">Delete</button>
</div>


public class ModalHelperBase:BlazorComponent {
        [Inject]
        private CampaignService campaignService { get; set; }
        [Parameter] protected CampaignInfo info { get; set; }

    }
```

Using the code above i can print a text  , but if i try to render the component i get the error :

```
blazor.server.js:23 Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.ArgumentException: There is no event handler with ID 7
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously(String assemblyName, String methodIdentifier, Object targetInstance, String argsJson)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.DotNetDispatcher.BeginInvoke(String callId, String assemblyName, String methodIdentifier, Int64 dotNetObjectId, String argsJson)
    at endInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.server.js:23)
```

Comment: You can just change your Task to accept a "campaign" and pass it the var ca.. but you will also need to be able to position the modal - so how you implement that will depend on how you design your modal, but personally I would probably place a modal component in another td at the end of the row and change it's visibility in OnMousePressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In your OnMousePressed method check which button was clicked.

```
if ( args.Button == 2) // right button clicked
{ 
   // Code to display your dialogbox
}
```

As for discovering which row was clicked, you can pass to your OnMousePressed method the value of ca.Id and do something with it.

Comment: I have edited my post .It seems i still can't render the subcomponent using the conditional.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? If not, tell me how many campaigns do you have ? Incidentally, you shouldn't use this.StateHasChanged(); in your OnClick event handler. This method is automatically called by Blazor after a DOM event.

Comment: Yes i solved my  problem .I know i shouldn't call it but sometimes in  a `@if(condition){ //render a component//}` and the argument that is changes its value , blazor does not reevaluate the condition.I saw i can bypass this problem by first calling `StateHasChanged` and then changing my conditional.(totally random ) like :  `void methodThatChangesCondition(){ this.StateHasChanged(); condition=true;}`